# "Uncaught ArgumentCountError: stripslashes() expects exactly 1 argument" while calling stripslashes() by function name with array_walk_recursive()

Tags: php, arrays, callback, stripslashes, array-walk

I'm trying to call `stripslashes()` on an array using `array_walk()`. It's not stripping slashes.

Here is my code:

```
$dataArr['xxx'] = '<script type=\'text/javascript\'><!--//<![CDATA[
           var m3_u = (location.protocol==\'https:\'?\'https://ads.test.com/www/delivery/ajs.php\':\'http://ads.test.com/www/delivery/ajs.php\');
           var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
           if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = \',\' etc.... etc....;
         ';
array_walk_recursive($dataArr, 'stripslashes');
print '<pre>'; print_r($dataArr); print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Some recommendations:

1) Remove the leading and ending spaces in your query.

2) `mysql_fetch_assoc` should be in lowercase.

3) Bare in mind that `mysql_fetch_assoc` only returns one row at a time. You need to work with a `while` loop to fetch all the results. See examples in the [documentation](http://us.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc).

4) You might prefer to use `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc`. See [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it's not stripping the slashes. It is returning the results.

Comment: You don't seem to need recursive behaviour... why don't you try with `array_walk` or `array_map`? Also, try with `mysql_fetch_array` in case there's something about associative arrays which might be bothering.

Comment: I tried array_walk and array_map and they both are not stripping the slashes. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`array_walk()` and `array_walk_recursive()` have a minimum function signature of 2 input parameters.  `stripslashes()` expects exactly 1 input parameter. When you call `stripslashes()` by name inside of a functional iterator, the excess parameter causes breakage.

If you want to call `stripslashes()` on every element of your flat, associative array using `array_walk()`, you'll need to write a custom function where the native function is called.  `array_walk_recursive()` is unnecessary on a flat array, but `array_walk()` and `array_map()` seem sensible.  `array_map()` returns the mutated array and the input is passed-in by value, so if you are happy to receive a new copy of the array, `array_map()`'s signature is better suited to calling by name.

```
array_walk($dataArr, fn(&$v) => $v = stripslashes($v));
```

or

```
$dataArr = array_map('stripslashes', $dataArr);
```